# Is there a facility to select a section of code and save it a seperate file in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I work with large html files that I would like to fragment into seperate files. The process of doing this is quite tedious as it requires copying the code, creating a new file, pasting it in the new file, and then selecting a folder and a name to save it under.

Is there a built-in shortcut or extension in Visual Studio 2017 and higher for making this easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate it in Visual Studio with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension. Select the code and call the following command (C# language):

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        string currentFileName = DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName;
        string newFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(currentFileName), System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(currentFileName) + "NewPart" + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(currentFileName));
        EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(newFileName, ts.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shucks. Is there something for VS Code?  I am working on a Mac and just realized it doesn't have the same

Comment: @ATL_DEV Sorry, don't know what can help for a Mac.

Comment: I revised my question so you're answer applies specifically for Visual Studio. I'll ask a seperate question for VS Studio. It is still the correct answer.